# How to display 24 items in a carousel - Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Im working in a project and currently I have a data file that display 24 clients in a page that im taking for a data file

```
 {% for client in site.data.clients %}
        <li>
          <a href="{{client.URL}}" target="_blank">
            <img src="{% asset_path {{client.image}} %}"
              alt="{{ client.alt }}">
          </a>
        </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

I would like to implement a carousel that display 12 items in one slide (and when clicked the arrow) display the other 12 items.

["Two slides with 12 elements each"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USZAm.jpg)

I've tried to implement that in the owl carousel but somehow is inserting me all the items in the first element of the first slide. still trying to find a way to split all the elements in two slides like the picture.

what i have implemented so far:

```
            <div class="testi-service owl-carousel owl-theme ">
             {% for client in site.data.clients %}
               {% if forloop.index > 24 %}
                 {% assign slidenum = 2 %}
               {% else %}
                 {% assign slidenum = 1 %}
              {% endif %}
          <div class="owl-item">
            <div class="oc-item slide{{ slidenum }}">
              <a href="{{client.URL}}" target="_blank">
                  <img src="{% asset_path {{client.image}} %}" alt="{{ client.alt }}">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

          {% endfor %}
        </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should just create 3 of these below each other: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html, and make them move at the same time. Would that be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the following Liquid:

```
{% for client in site.data.clients %}

  {% if forloop.index > 12 %}
    {% assign slidenum = 2 %}
  {% else %}
    {% assign slidenum = 1 %}
  {% endif %}

  <li class="slide{{ slidenum }}">
    <a href="{{client.URL}}" target="_blank">
      <img src="{% asset_path {{client.image}} %}" alt="{{ client.alt }}">
    </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

And this css:

```
.slide2 {display:none;}
```

You can control the carousel with the following jQuery:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  $("[class^='slide']").toggle();
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it worked like this. just trying to fix the resizing and responsive problem at the moment

```
<div class=" col-md-9 clients side padding-content">
  <div class="client-carousel">
      <div class="container">
            <div class="owl-item">
                <div class="oc-item">
                  <ul class="clients-grid grid-6 nobottommargin clearfix">
                      {% comment %}
                        `site.data.clients` defined in `_data/clients.yml`
                      {% endcomment %}
                      {% for client in site.data.clients %}
                        {% if forloop.index > 24 %}
                          {% assign slidenum = 2 %}
                        {% else %}
                          {% assign slidenum = 1 %}
                        {% endif %}
                        <li class="slide{{ slidenum }}">
                          <a href="{{client.URL}}" target="_blank">
                            <img src="{% asset_path {{client.image}} %}" alt="{{ client.alt }}">
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container">

              <div class="owl-item">
                  <div class="oc-item">
                    <ul class="clients-grid grid-6 nobottommargin clearfix">
                        {% comment %}
                          `site.data.clients` defined in `_data/clients.yml`
                        {% endcomment %}
                        {% for client in site.data.clients %}
                          {% if forloop.index > 24 %}
                            {% assign slidenum = 2 %}
                          {% else %}
                            {% assign slidenum = 1 %}
                          {% endif %}
                          <li class="slide{{ slidenum }}">
                            <a href="{{client.URL}}" target="_blank">
                              <img src="{% asset_path {{client.image}} %}" alt="{{ client.alt }}">
                            </a>
                          </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>

        </div>




</div>
```